# How can I send G-code to a Bambu Labs X1/X1C?

Tags: g-code, bambu

What are the ways that G-code can be sent to a Bambu Labs X1/X1C?

Comment: Without wishing to sound pedantic, could you be a little more specific? Do you mean "Are there any unusual or undocumented ways?" I don't have this printer, but looking at the [manual](https://manuals.plus/bambu-lab/x1-3d-printer-manual-2) the **only** connectivity seems to be via Wi-Fi (using either a mobile app or an application running on a PC/Mac) - there doesn't appear to be an SD card slot, nor USB interface. Although there is mention of a *Bambu Bus*, but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Do the printers actually exist? I only see pre-order tickets.

Comment: @0scar there have been some going to YouTubers, etc. that have prerelease versions.

Comment: There is indeed an SD card slot, at least on the X1C.  So, as long as you can generate the G-code externally, you can run it.  Not sure that answers OPs question about "sending" G-code, but it's doable.